# Make a legend of connected attributes in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: legend, arcgis-pro

I am having some trouble with ArcGIS Pro to create a legend. I have some x-y data plotted, with colours according to "unique values" and the size of the symbol as a "connected" attribute to another value so my symbols are proportional to it (sample size in this case).

When I try to create a legend in the "Design view" through "Insert Legend" and then in the "Design" stript select only the layer that has this x-y features, what appears in the legend are the colours and the "unique values" they represent. However, what I want is to create a legend for the symbol sizes, something that would look similar to this:

[image: legend]